# Node-RED nodes not deployed

Tags: ibm-cloud, node-red

What if I can't deploy additional Node-RED nodes anymore. I can add them to an existing and small flow, but they have this little blue dot, even when I click on DEPLOY.

Answer (score 0):

seems like the nodes do get deployed, just the blue dots don't dissapear for some reason even after restart